# How to integrate private remote gitlab repository (self hosted) as swift package manager in xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github, gitlab

I have one repository with a URL that looks like this:

https://someselfhostedwebsiteurl/gitlab/data/sdkisoname.git

(As this is private lib I cannot write the real URL.)

I am trying to add it as a Swift package from Xcode but it is returning unknown error occurred error. I am trying to solve for more than a week but I could not come up with the solution. It is self-hosted GitLab files so is there any additional setup I need to do? I am seeking help for this please suggest some solution to solve this integration issue.

[Click to see the screenshot of Unknown Error occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGoyg.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution to this issue?